# Excel averaging every 24 rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

On the left there is an hourly calculation for the amount of water in a lake and the depth of the lake.
On the right I want the average of every day, so the average of 24 cells.
How do I get the average of J12-J36 in R12 with a function that I can drag down?

[image]

Comment: =AVERAGE(Select the cells J12 to J36) When you drag, the start cell and end cell will automatically update

Comment: If I drag it with this formula I will have the average of J13 to J37 in R13 but I want the average of J37-J60 in R13. I needs to go in steps of 24

Comment: So you want R12 = AVERAGE(J12:J36), R13 = AVERAGE(J36:J60), R14 = AVERAGE(J60:J84) and so forth? (adding 24 each time to the row)

Comment: Yes! exactly that

Comment: But not including the last one, so R12 = AVERAGE(J12:J36), R13 = AVERAGE(J37:J60), R14 = AVERAGE(J61:J84) and so forth? (adding 24 each time to the row)

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX to set your range:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(J:J,12+(ROW(1:1)-1)*24):INDEX(J:J,36+(ROW(1:1)-1)*24))
```

[image]

Comment: This gives me an error. "The formula you typed contains an error." I researched it in other forums and keep getting the same problem. Somehow its not working

Comment: Do you use `;` instead of `,` to delineate the criteria?

Comment: It keeps highlighting the second J in the formula, somehow there is a problem with the array and/or reference?

Comment: I just copied and pasted the formula directly into excel and it works just fine for me.

Comment: Got it! bloody ; / , switch! Thanks so much brooo